# Would I be able to join multiple queries to solve an issue where one query is not working within a while loop?

Tags: php

I have a list of blog posts where the first image of a set uploaded with the post information is displayed as a thumbnail on the list. I am having an issue where I have one `while` loop running to display a list of blog posts and another `while` loop within the first that calls for the image belonging to a specific post id to be displayed as a preview.

My first query (which I'll refer to as `$query`) runs perfectly fine. My query where I am trying to display the images I'll refer to as `$query1`. If I put `$query1` within the `$query` loop, it returns a non-object error. If I put `$query1` outside of `$query`, it works perfectly fine.

*I will post my full code below this written explanation of my issue.*

I also wanted to mention that I have the same exact `$query1` code that I am trying to make work here, working without a hitch on another page. However, on the other page, it is not nested within another `while` loop and is existing on it's own.

Would it be possible to somehow join

`$imgsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$post_id' LIMIT 1";`

this query with

`$queryString = "SELECT post_id, title, price, image, LEFT(description, 180) AS description, category FROM post INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=post.category_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";`

this query?

After tinkering around, I found that if I changed the `$query1` to `$query`, the images would at least display where they needed to. However, I know I cannot have those conflicting names if I want things to work. I just did it for the heck of it to see if anything changed.

That's why I'm wondering if I can combine the queries into one, I could possibly get it to function the way I want it to? I just don't know how to go about doing that while keeping the `LIMIT 1` intact and *only* affecting the images. If that's even possible for me to do. I just started with PHP not too long ago, so this is all a learning process for me.

I've been working at this for a couple days and I have not yet found a solution. I've browsed through dozens of topics on this forum and others trying to find any information to help me.

This is a non-wordpress blog I am working with. I am also aware that I should be using prepared statements for security, but my main focus right now is just getting this function to work.

**Here is my code in it's entirety from the part of the html where the post previews are being generated:**

```
<?php
      $queryString = "SELECT post_id, title, price, image, LEFT(description, 180) AS description, category FROM post INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=post.category_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page"; 
      $query = $db->prepare($queryString);
      $query->execute();
      $query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $price, $image, $description, $category);

            while ($query->fetch()):
        $lastspace = strrpos($description, '');
        ?>

    <article>
      <div class="preview">
         <?php
            $i = 0;
          ?>
        <!-- PROBLEM AREA IS HERE -->
        <?php 
            $imgsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$post_id' LIMIT 1";
            $query1 = $db->query($imgsql);
            if($query1->num_rows>0){
              while ($imgrow = $query1->fetch_object()){  
              echo "<img src='admin/images/".$imgrow->img_name."' width='150px' height='150px' >";
            }
          }
        ?> 
        <!-- END PROBLEM AREA -->

        <div class="info">
          <h2><?php echo $title?></h2> 
          <div class="price">
           $<?php echo $price?>
          </div>
          <div class="cat">
          <?php echo $category?>
          </div>
          <div class="description">
          <?php echo substr($description, $lastspace).'...<br><a href="post.php?id='.$post_id.'">VIEW PRODUCT</a>'?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile?>
```

**Here is the portion that is giving me issues:**

```
         <?php
            $i = 0;
          ?>

        <?php 
            $imgsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$post_id' LIMIT 1";
            $query1 = $db->query($imgsql);
            if($query1->num_rows>0){
              while ($imgrow = $query1->fetch_object()){  
              echo "<img src='admin/images/".$imgrow->img_name."' width='150px' height='150px' >";
            }
          }
        ?>
```

**This is the specific line where the error is:**

`if($query1->num_rows>0){`

When I run `var_dump($query1);` it returns `bool(false)` on this line.

As mentioned before, I think the query `$query` that it's nested in is causing the issue. Just out of curiosity, I placed

```
<?php 
            $imgsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path FROM images WHERE post_id = '$post_id' LIMIT 1";
            $query1 = $db->query($imgsql);
            if($query1->num_rows>0){
              while ($imgrow = $query1->fetch_object()){  
              echo "<img src='admin/images/".$imgrow->img_name."' width='150px' height='150px' >";
            }
          }
        ?>
```

above (rather than nesting it within)

```
<?php
      $queryString = "SELECT post_id, title, price, image, LEFT(description, 180) AS description, category FROM post INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=post.category_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page"; 
      $query = $db->prepare($queryString);
      $query->execute();
      $query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $price, $image, $description, $category);

            while ($query->fetch()):
        $lastspace = strrpos($description, '');
        ?>
```

and an image displayed and it worked fine.

However, I need it to exist within the `while` loop in the above query to function how I need it so that each post preview can have it's unique image that was uploaded with it.

Could this possibly have anything to do with me having one `while` nested within another `while`?

Hopefully I can give a clear enough explanation of this issue. Let me know if I need to clarify anything. I can always provide screenshots of visual examples of what's happening if that would help.

Thank you in advance to anyone with suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried testing the sql scripts to see what each of them return with a small sample? Also try and feed the problematic sql script with an array of values (without using while that works)

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet. I'm going to give that a go now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get everything working by adding `$query->store_result();` into my first query.

```
<?php
      $queryString = "SELECT post_id, title, price, image, LEFT(description, 180) AS description, category FROM post INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=post.category_id ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page"; 
      $query = $db->prepare($queryString);
      $query->execute();
      $query->store_result();
      $query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $price, $image, $description, $category);

            while ($query->fetch()):
        $lastspace = strrpos($description, '');
        ?>
```

After doing so, everything worked the way I wanted it to. Apparently there is an issue with running a second query before the results from the first query have been consumed.